# sqlite3 uri syntax in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

[These examples](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html#urifilenameexamples) from the sqlite documentation show this is a valid uri as understood by sqlite3:

```
file:data.db
```

However, when I use this format as given by the [sqlite-nodejs tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/connect/):

```
let db = new sqlite3.Database('file:data.db', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log('Connected to the chinook database.');
});
```

My directory gets a file written to it called:

```
file:data.db
```

This looked like a valid uri.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The node bindings probably aren't calling [sqlite3_open_v2()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) with the right options to enable URI filename syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node bindings aren't a full featured API.  You cannot use a URI.